# Display image gallery with ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview

I want to do so: Press the button opens gallery, choose a picture and it appears in the program ImageView. Picture selected all works only displayed nothing, just an empty area.

```
//upload photo
        uploadPhoto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                final int SELECT_PHOTO = 1234;
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
            }
        });

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 
            switch(requestCode) { 
                case 1234:
                    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

                        Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                        ImageView photoRegistration = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.testSet);
                        photoRegistration.setImageURI(selectedImage);

                    }
            }
    }
```

**xml**

```
<ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/testSet"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/common_signin_btn_icon_pressed_light" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with:

Bitmap bitmap_photo = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);